# How to use Go to get the Github commit history of a given file of a repository

Tags: go, github

Like the title said, my question here is how to use Go to programmatically get the Github commit history of a given file in a given repository

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to access `GitHub` api from golang. There are a plenty of libraries but I would recommend using [**go-github**](https://github.com/google/go-github).

Here is how you can try doing that

```
package main

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/google/go-github/github"
)

func main() {

    var username string = "MayukhSobo"
    client := github.NewClient(nil)
    commits, response, err := client.Repositories.ListCommits(context.Background(), username, "Awesome-Snippets", nil)
    if err != nil && response.StatusCode != 200 {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, commit := range commits {
        // commit.SHA
        // commit.Files
        // You can use the commit
    }

}
```

If you are trying to access the some other public repo, you need to pass the owner name in the `username` and change the repo name.

If you face access issues, it can be probably it is a private repo. You can also use the key pair to set up the access.